# C# WPF TreeView свойство SelectedItem попросту отсутствует

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет, есть такая проблема: пытаюсь привязать выбранный TreeViewItem к свойству во ViewModel, читаю на всех форумах, о том, что это свойство доступно только для чтения, а у меня оно вообще отсутствует. Что я делаю не так? .Net Framework 4.7.2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пишите без подсказки и выставляйте привязку OneWayToSource

Comment: Свойство "SelectedItem" не имеет доступного метода задания. И в конструкторе ошибка предварительного показа.

Comment: Покажите что написали

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1000040/6766879

Comment: '  <TreeView Background="Transparent" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                      Mode=OneWayToSource}"  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeItems}">

            </TreeView>' 
@АндрейNOP

Comment: Так там у него, видимо, это свойство доступно, а я вообще никак не могу его установить.

Comment: Решение по ссылке на старшем SO: либо наследование, либо AP, либо AB